How to Create a Dynamic Chart Range Based on a Cell Value
I am trying to create a dynamic chart range in Excel based on a cell value. Specifically, I want to plot data from column P starting at row 3 up to the row number specified in cell H5.
For example:

My data is in column P, starting from P3.
Cell H5 contains the value 180, indicating that the range should be P3:P180

I have tried using the INDIRECT function but encountered issues when setting this as the chart's data source. Here are the steps and formulas I have tried:

Calculating the dynamic range in a helper cell:
=INDIRECT("P3:P" & H5)

Using the OFFSET function directly in the chart:
=OFFSET($P$3, 0, 0, $H$5 - 2)


Neither approach works correctly when I try to set the chart's data range using these formulas.
Steps Taken:

I inserted a blank chart.

I went to 'Select Data' and attempted to add a series with the dynamic range formula.

I tried using OFFSET and INDIRECT in various ways but the chart did not update dynamically as expected.


What I Need:
I need a method to dynamically update the chart's data range based on the value in cell H5, without manually adjusting the range each time the value changes.
Example:

Data range: P3
(if H5 contains 180)
Dynamic range formula: Should reflect changes in H5 automatically.

Question:
How can I set a chart's data range dynamically based on a cell value in Excel? Is there a way to use INDIRECT, OFFSET, or another method to achieve this?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

So H5 says how many rows are needed to be seen by the chart, but would this range extend beyond that 180? In other words, are you able to turn this into a table range and have it dynamically see the data that way through filters? It could be as simple as a column that says if( row( [currentrow]) <= H5, "Include","Exclude")  The way to use indirect and offset would be to create a named range and feed that into the chart.

The P cell contains an array of balances, and the chart is drawn based on P. However, there are a significant number of zeros towards the end of the P column. If I plot the chart using the usual method, the latter part of the chart gets filled with these zeros. To prevent this, I have placed the number of valid entries in cell H5.

So similarly you can have a column in say, Q, that looks at the row P and if the row is lower than what is in H5 label it to exclude and filter that out with a pivot chart. Then all that is required to update the chart is a right-click refresh
